# Tomcat on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, tomcat7

I have created a JSP / servlets application running in Tomcat 7.  It runs fine on my development machine, and I deployed it as a WAR file to my Windows Server Amazon EC2 instance after installing Tomcat.  I can access it locally (localhost:8080 etc) on the EC2 instance, but I cannot access it externally at all.  I've done the following:

- Set up Elastic IP for the instance
- Open port 8080 in a Security Group

I tried going directly to the root address (i.e. not my application url) and got a default IIS page.  So I disabled IIS, thinking it might be getting in Tomcat's way, but no dice.  I've searched around a fair bit, and everything I've found seems to amount to what I've already done.  Any suggestions?

++++ EDIT ++++
Never mind.  It was Windows firewall.  I can't close the question yet because I'm too new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a Windows firewall issue.

Answer (score 0):

By default, you need to create fold called ROOT and some default page inside like default.html in the webapps, and that you can visit your site by 8080